# Why does Postman require user login for Google oauth?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, postman, google-shopping-api

I'll try to connect to the content api for shopping via API.
I'de tried some different oAuth ways (e.g. "three-step-method" with access key and baerer-token) but for a spezific integration I need the "credentials-oAuth".

Currently I tried as following:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?
client_id=[my client id]&
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/content&
redirect_uri=[some random request bin -> added in Authorised redirect URIs ]&
response_type=code
```

If I call this via Postman, I'll be redirected to the login page of Google. But why?

How can I solve this problem?`

BG
David

Answer (score 1):

Shopping API data is private user data.  In order for your application to access private user data it must have the permission of the user who owns that data.

We use OAuth2 to do that. The user must consent to your application accessing its data. In the below image the application Google analytics windows is asking the user for permission to access their Google analytics data.

[image]

> If I call this via Postman, I'll be redirected to the login page of Google. But why?

You are seeing a login screen with Postman is simple the user needs to be logged in before they can grant access to their data.

> How can I solve this problem?

You dont as there is no problem the user must login to grant your client application consent to its data.  This is working exactly as it should

**Service accounts**
Update to answer comment [Service accounts](https://developers.google.com/shopping-content/v2/how-tos/service-accounts) are special Google accounts that can be used by applications to access Google APIs programmatically via OAuth 2.0. A service account uses an OAuth 2.0 flow that does not require human authorization. Instead, it uses a key file that only your application can access. This guide discusses how to access the Content API for Shopping with service accounts.

Comment: If I wanna call the google API via e.g. another cloud plattform, how is it possible to get the data in two steps? 
Step 1) Get a key with credentials (generated API oAuth Cred)
Step 2) Get data with this key

Comment: Check my update you should try and use service accounts

Comment: Is there an alternative to Postman that isn't 100MB and doesn't require login?

Comment: Accessing private data will always require login.